# How to have Router object in Angular without injection?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In angular i want to have an instance of `Router` (from @angular/Router) but it wants many parameters for its constructor. I don't know these parameters. Can I have an instance without injection and how?

Comment: why can't you inject it?

Comment: you can't get is any other way. Angular run-time creates this instance of the Router and and you can only get it via injection. If you create using constructor it would be just a useless object that has no connection to the application.

Answer (score 1):

you can inject angular `Injector` and get the `Router`:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.router = injector.get(Router);
}
```

Comment: But I don't have a constructor.
only There is a utility file contains some functions that are exported to use in another files and in one of these functions I have to use `Router` and as I said ..

Comment: I think my answer is in this link (https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#create), but I can't find my own solution from it. can you help me !

Answer (score -3):

You don't need any parameters for an instance of `Router`. I think you're somehow not injecting it correctly. This is how you do it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-default-nav',
  templateUrl: './default-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default-nav.component.css']
})
export class DefaultNavComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

}
```

You can then reference the `Router` in typescript with `this.router` and in your html code with just `router`